# How to programmatically select feature with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a problem. I have a map with OpenLayers layer. Next i have a list with features of layer.
I want to select feature in this list and edit this.
So i need how to add feature to `OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature`.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about calling the `select` (1) method of your `SelectFeature` control?

1 - http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.select

Comment: I try do this but not work.`var ffff = featureManager.featureLayer.getFeaturesByAttribute("id",'123');``alert(ffff.length);``this.selectControl.select(ffff[0]);`. Alert give me "1" but object not selected.